# Query multiple meta values at the same time :

Tags: custom-field, meta-query

Here's my query :

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'pc-portables-gamer', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'meta_query' => array(

    array( 'key' => 'modele_du_processeur', 'value' => $_GET['modele_du_processeur'] , 'compare' => 'LIKE' ), 'relation' => 'AND'

    ));

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And here's my search form :

```
<form action="<?php $GET_['SERVER_URI'] ?>" method="get">

    <input type="checkbox" name="modele_du_processeur" value="Core i3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="modele_du_processeur" value="Core i5" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="modele_du_processeur" value="Core i7" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
</form>
```

Could someone please tell me how to get posts with "Core i5" AND those with "Core i7" ?

Checking two boxes (ie : &modele_du_processeur=Core+i5&modele_du_processeur=Core+i7) gets me only the last  value !

I have tried to name my inputs "modele_du_processeur[]", but the query is invalid and gets me all the posts (the string is modele_du_processeur%5B%5D=Core+i5&modele_du_processeur%5B%5D=Core+i7)

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your search form, PHP uses fieldname[] notation to accept multiple values for a parameter name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="modele_du_processeur[]" value="Core i3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="modele_du_processeur[]" value="Core i5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="modele_du_processeur[]" value="Core i7" />
```

Once that's done, you will get an array in `$_GET["modele_du_processeur"]`, so you can work with

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'pc-portables-gamer',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'key' => 'modele_du_processeur', 'value' => $_GET['modele_du_processeur'] , 'compare' => 'IN' )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```